# Little/big endian integer types in user space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, endianness, libc, userspace

I'm going to use `struct` [solaris_x86_slice](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.5/source/include/linux/genhd.h#L476) from linux kernel header in user space. Struct is defined as:

```
struct solaris_x86_slice {
    __le16 s_tag;       /* ID tag of partition */
    __le16 s_flag;      /* permission flags */
    __le32 s_start;     /* start sector no of partition */
    __le32 s_size;      /* # of blocks in partition */
};
```

Should I use as byte order fixed types these kernel space specific types `__le16`, `__le32` (via `<linux/types.h>`) or is there anything user space specific which major libc implementations (glibc, uclibc, musl) implement?

I don't see any type in `<endian.h>`, there are only conversion functions, so I incline to use `__le16`, `__le32` .

Comment: There is nothing magic about the types. E.g. `__le16` is equivalent to `uint16_t`. The kernel uses the special types for type-checking by the "sparse" checker to make sure that conversions between host byte order data and endian-specific data have been accounted for by the developer. You can think of the types as documentation, and an indication that you should use the user-space functions from `<endian.h>` to convert the values to and from host byte order.

Comment: @IanAbbott: You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: @IanAbbott would it really work the same on both little and big endian architectures? We've find quite a few bugs for s390 kernel, which is big endian (code is usually written for intel, which is little endian).

Comment: @pevik Bugs can be fixed, but it is up to the programmer to take big/little-endian differences into account. In user space, the functions in `<endian.h>` provide the facilities to allow the code to correct for endian differences, but it is up to the programmer to use them.